# Can this random sampling loop be vectorised for optimisation?

Tags: for-loop, vectorization, octave, permutation

I'm trying to find how to vectorize FOR loop in the code below:

```
h=load('water-column');                 % load file 
perm=5;                         % make 10000 permutation
n_1=5;                            % number of random sample
dm_ale=zeros(1,perm);               % create a vector 
sz=length(h);                     % count size of matrix data    
for k=1:perm                      % making loop for the permutation
    i_1=randsample(sz,n_1);      
    x_3=h(i_1);            
    x_4=h(setdiff(1:sz,i_1));    
    dm_ale(k)=abs(mean(x_3)-mean(x_4)); % calculate difference of mean for each permutation
end
```

As for the file input, I have something like this (just a sample, the real file contains more data):

```
   3792.615000000000
   3792.625000000000
   3792.634000000000
   3792.640000000000
   3792.647000000000
   3792.654000000000
   3792.662000000000
   3792.668000000000
   3792.673000000000
```

I can't figure out where I can put the increment in a vectorized statement. Is it possible to vectorize this?

As the code that Cris Luengo (sorry, I can't figure out how to tag user) proposed, I bump into an error :

```
error: randsample: The input k must be a non-negative integer. Sampling without replacement needs k <= n.
error: called from
    randsample at line 46 column 5
    random_sampling at line 8 column 5
```

where `random_sampling` is the name of the code.

Initially I need to have `perm`=10000 (to have robust random sampling test) and `n_1`=600 (population number needed so that my test could work). The code above seems to not work even if I obey the condition: `n_1^2` << `perm`. 
I'm assuming that the error is due to `n_1` which is still considerably big enough related to `perm`.
Any other lead? I'm thinking about increasing `perm`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "how can I vectorize" question, but you can probably save yourself some flops by noticing that mean(x_4) = (sum(h) - sum(x_3))/(sz-n_1). Since you can calculate sum(h) outside the loop, this will save you the need to create x_4 and to calculate its mean, which is useful if sz is large.

Comment: You cannot use `randsample` to generate multiple random samplings at once. If `h` is sufficiently large, you can create a random sampling with `perm*n_1` elements, then divide that up into `perm` sets. That might be approximately OK, but is not exactly the same as what you're doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `randsample` to generate multiple random samplings at once (or so it seems from reading the documentation). If `h` is sufficiently large, and `perm` and `n_1` are sufficiently small (`sz` >> `perm*n_1`), then you can create a random sampling with `perm*n_1` elements, then divide that up into `perm` sets. That might be approximately OK, but is not exactly the same as what you're doing now.

Your code would then look like this (using the simplification suggested by Geoffrey Brent [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316770/octave-can-this-for-loop-be-vectorised-for-optimisation#comment95453887_54316770)):

```
h = load('col-deau');
perm = 5;
n_1 = 5;
sz = numel(h);  % numel is always better than length if you use one index h(i_1) rather than two h(i_1,1)
sum_h = sum(h)
i_1 = randsample(sz, n_1 * perm);
i_1 = reshape(i_1, n_1, perm);
x_3 = h(i_1);                    % x_3 has the same size as i_1
x_3 = sum(x_3, 1);               % sum over columns, x_3 has perm elements now
x_4 = sum_h - x_3;
dm_ale = abs(x_3 / n_1 - x_4 / (sz-n_1));
```

If `perm` is also large (as indicated in a comment), but `n_1` is still small, you can approximate this using a random sampling with replacement (with small `n_1`, the chance you have a repeated element in one set is small):

```
i_1 = randsample(sz, n_1 * perm, true);
```

Comment: If a small effect from repeated elements is not acceptable, there are a couple of options. One is to do it in the way you've posted, but then to check for repeats and "reroll" those elements only, repeating until no repeats remain. Another is, for `j=1:n_1`, generate a column of randoms drawn from `1:sz+1-j`, then treat this as a selection from the values not already picked in previous columns. For instance, `i_1=randsample(sz,perm)`, `i_2=randsample(sz-1,perm)`, and then for rows where `i_2>=i_1`, increment i_2 by 1. (Apologies for piggybacking, my Octave is too rusty for a full answer.)

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent: Rerolling is a good option, but could become costly if `n_1` increases. I like the other option better, but then you're back to a loop. :)

Comment: In fact, for `n_1>2` it ends up being a double loop since avoiding duplicates requires checking 'i_j' against the previous 'j-1' vectors. But as long as `n_1^2` << `perm`, which appears to be the case here, that might not be so bad.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hello, thanks for replying ! I've tried running the above code but it run into an error. I'll update the question.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Hi, thanks for the suggestions. However, I've tried to perform the condition that you stated but apparently the code run into an error. Please see question update.

Comment: @MochammadHusniRizal The error message explains the problem: by default randsample samples without replacement, but if perm is large relative to sz, you're trying to sample more values than there are available to sample. You probably need to set replacement=true in the randsample call.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent yep, have set replacement=true in order for it to work. Since it's random sampling, I don't think it makes a difference with or without replacement.